# MySQL update column from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I want to grab the total number of skills required for a specific job position and update this table's column with that information.

The tskill column is the one intended for the information to be updated to.

```
pnum  sname  
===============
001   cooking        
001   cleaning
002   teaching
003   driving

pnum   ptitle  tskill          
===================
001   chef  
002   teacher
003   driving instructor
```

Sample data with relevant columns (tskill is a new added column in POSITIONS which is currently all empty)

```
INSERT INTO POSITIONS VALUES ( 001, 'chef')
INSERT INTO POSITIONS VALUES ( 002, 'teacher')
INSERT INTO POSITIONS VALUES ( 003, 'driving instructor')

INSERT INTO SNEEDED VALUES ( 001, 'cooking');
INSERT INTO SNEEDED VALUES ( 001, 'cleaning');
INSERT INTO SNEEDED VALUES ( 002, 'teaching');
INSERT INTO SNEEDED VALUES ( 003, 'driving');
```

Any tips for doing this with the update statement?

Comment: What query that you try?

Comment: I have tried using an inner join, but confused how I would get the total count, I am new to this language

Comment: Do neither of the answers work for you? If not, could you please provide more information to help us answer your question.

Comment: Your answer was the correct solution, I just had to disable the safe updates feature. Thank you

Comment: Cool. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to update the position table using this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbd76f/1)):

```
UPDATE POSITIONS
SET tskill = (SELECT COUNT(pnum)
              FROM SNEEDED WHERE SNEEDED.pnum = POSITIONS.pnum)
```

Output:

```
select * from POSITIONS;

pnum    ptitle              tskill
1       chef                2
2       teacher             1
3       driving instructor  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this answer as per your question. Have a look again. What we are doing here is , we are selecting the count of pnum from sneeded table with the similar pnum and updating to positions table  where pnum matches. Hope this helps.

```
UPDATE position as p
(
  SELECT pnum, count(pnum) as skill FROM sneeeded
  GROUP BY pnum
) as n
SET p.tskill = n.skill
 where p.pnum = n.pnum
```

Comment: There is loaded data in t1, some job positions identified by position number require multiple skills. I want to get the count of how many skills are required for each position by updating that data to the t2 (tskill). t1 contains the skills required for a job identified by the pnum, and t2 contains the position title of the job.

Comment: So are you trying to update the count(pnum) from table 1 to tskills of table2 where table1 pnum is equal to table2 pnum?? Can you add the sample data in your question.?

Comment: Just updated my question.
I want to store the number (decimal type) of skills a certain job position may require. (i.e. the Chef position, requires you to have skills of 'cooking' and 'cleaning', so the 'tskill' column I want to contain, ("chef", 2). As in 2 skills are required for the job. Thank you and hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, however @Nick supplied the correct solution for me.